# How to write all variables to a JSON file in the python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, xonsh

Let's say I have created some variables in the python shell. I want to do something like this:

```
>>> animal="Cat"
>>> age="2"
>>> weight="3.8"
>>> name="Kitty"
>>> env.saveTo("./Cat.json")
>>> env.clear()
>>> env.loadFrom("./Cat.json")
```

Is it possible? I am using `xonsh`.

Comment: what is `env` in here?

Comment: `env` is some python `object` or `package` needed for me that facilitates the required functionality

Answer (score 1):

Using `xonsh` I did

```
$ xonsh
$ animal="Cat"
$ age="2"
$ weight="3.8"
$ name="Kitty"
$ history > Cat
$ exit
$ xonsh
$ source Cat
```

Huh! Finally, I avoided `jupyter notebook`.